# Sending Mail issue in FastAPI

Tags: fastapi

I have been trying to send email to the user using the FastAPi-mail. But I am getting below error message:
MAIL_PORT = int(os.getenv('MAIL_PORT'))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
Here, is the directory structure: [image]
I have defined my .env file with the following information

```
MAIL_USERNAME="my user name"
MAIL_PASSWORD="$$$$"
MAIL_FROM="xyz@gmail.com"
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_SERVER="smtp.gmail.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="FastAPI"
```

This is my send_email.py file:

```
import os
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks
from fastapi_mail import FastMail, MessageSchema, ConnectionConfig
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('.env')
class Envs:
    MAIL_USERNAME = os.getenv('MAIL_USERNAME')
    MAIL_PASSWORD = os.getenv('MAIL_PASSWORD')
    MAIL_FROM = os.getenv('MAIL_FROM')
    MAIL_PORT = int(os.getenv('MAIL_PORT'))
    MAIL_SERVER = os.getenv('MAIL_SERVER')
    MAIL_FROM_NAME = os.getenv('MAIN_FROM_NAME')

conf = ConnectionConfig(
    MAIL_USERNAME=Envs.MAIL_USERNAME,
    MAIL_PASSWORD=Envs.MAIL_PASSWORD,
    MAIL_FROM=Envs.MAIL_FROM,
    MAIL_PORT=Envs.MAIL_PORT,
    MAIL_SERVER=Envs.MAIL_SERVER,
    MAIL_FROM_NAME=Envs.MAIL_FROM_NAME,
    MAIL_TLS=True,
    MAIL_SSL=False,
    USE_CREDENTIALS=True,
    TEMPLATE_FOLDER='./templates/'
)

async def send_email_async(subject: str, email_to: str, body: dict):
    message = MessageSchema(
        subject=subject,
        recipients=[email_to],
        template_body=body,
        subtype='html',
    )
    
    fm = FastMail(conf)
    await fm.send_message(message, template_name='email.html')

def send_email_background(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, subject: str, email_to: str, body: dict):
    message = MessageSchema(
        subject=subject,
        recipients=[email_to],
        template_body=body,
        subtype='html',
    )
    fm = FastMail(conf)
    background_tasks.add_task(
       fm.send_message, message, template_name='email.html')
```

This is my main file:

```
@app.get('/send-email/asynchronous')
async def send_email_asynchronous():
    await send_email.send_email_async('Hello World','someemail@gmail.com',
    {'title': 'Hello World', 'name': 'John Doe'})
    return 'Success'
@app.get('/send-email/backgroundtasks')
def send_email_backgroundtasks(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    send_email.send_email_background(background_tasks, 'Hello World',   
    'someemail@gmail.com', {'title': 'Hello World', 'name':       'John Doe'})
    return 'Success'
```

I was following this blog: [text](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-send-email-using-python-fastapi-947921059f0c). Does anyone face this issue? As far as I know if we want to send email to gmail then the port should be 587. But getting the none type value is weird here. Thanks

Comment: If `MAIL_PORT=587` is really true then the code should work. Please make sure you provide a [mre].

Comment: Where is the location of your .env file?

Comment: I have the project directory structure here attached. Its in the main directory.

Answer (score 0):

Remove '.env' from your `load_dotenv` call. If it is in the same directory, load_dotenv should find it. Just do

```
load_dotenv()
```

Also, you don't need quotes in your .env file

```
MAIL_USERNAME=my user name
MAIL_PASSWORD=$$$$
MAIL_FROM=xyz@gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_SERVER=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=FastAPI
```

Comment: Does connection configure file total parameters need to be same as environment variable? New error:  File "D:\Mapping_the_world\send_email.py", line 15, in <module> conf = ConnectionConfig(
  File "pydantic\env_settings.py", line 39, pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 4 validation errors for ConnectionConfig
MAIL_STARTTLS field required (type=value_error.missing). MAIL_STARTTLS
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
MAIL_SSL_TLS
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
MAIL_SSL, MAIL_TLS extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)

Comment: They're required by the model, you can set them as environment variables too.

Comment: And you should remove MAIL_TLS